# Xcode manual signing works but not Automatic signing

Tags: ios, xcode

I am able to archive our app. When I tried to Distribute it and select *"Automatically manage signing"* I got an error say *"No Apple Distribution certificate found for *. A certificate is required for App Store connect distribution"*

But if I select *"Manually manage signing"*, and fill in the Distribution certificate and profile fields the signing works as expected!

It seems Xcode can't locate the certificate or profile when using automatic signing? Any thought with this?

If there's no certificate or profile like the error says, then there shouldn't be any to select from when using manual signing! but I'm able to select a certificate and profile when I do manual signing.

Answer (score 0):

I think my issue is because the NEW FORMAT Apple distribution certificate is not installed in my machine thus when I select "automatic signing" the error will popup.

The "manual signing" is still working because Xcode allows me to select the OLD FORMAT Apple distribution certificate which is still valid.

I resolve this issue by installing the NEW FORMAT of the Apple Distribution Certificate.